# git - two branches named the same? Difference is one lower case - one mixed case?

Tags: windows, git, git-branch

I am so used to typing in camelCase that I have been doing it in git.  That is - until I realized git is case sensitive!!   File names included.

From history - at the start of this production branch - it was ClientMgr.    But just at the start.

All the work past the initial commit - has been on branch - clientmgr.

A few hours ago - I realized the problem.    Since the tree was straight - and not branches - I tried deleting ClientMgr.   Right after - I had 195 new files when before all was clean.

Unsure - I restored a backup - but now have two branches - with the same name - different cases.

Do I continue on - and just ignore the ClientMgr?   Or is there a sane way to clean this up?

I would really love to end up with one.  I have some ideas - but tired at gitting shot it...

Any and all suggestions appreciated.

P.S. - guess this helps explain why I had some missing / lost changes a few days ago.

I love git - hope to get past or mostly past the got-ya's
+++++++++++++++++++++++
Edit: 4/1/2013

The ClientMgr was the original branch - with one commit.   I continued working (thinking I was on the ClientMgr branch but instead the new clientmgr branch.

I am concerned because of the same name - different case I think is potential time bomb.  That is I suspect - git mostly treats them as separate - but not always.  For example - when on ClientMgr - and trying to check clientmgr - I get an error message that I am already on it.

Seeing this - there could be other problems looming with this.

I think my first step will be to backup again - and then try to rename ClientMgr to where there is not similarity - and test and see how that goes.

It that goes well - at least I have (or may have) taken care of the

Once again - I greatly appreciate everyone input.

Jim H

+++++++++++++++++++++++++
Edit 2

Not what expected - but seems ok

I renamed ClientMgr to oldclientmgr via
git branch -m ClientMgr oldclientmgr

Looking at the tree in SourceTree - it renamed both to oldclientmgr
I checked the graph - and I looked to be where I wanted to be
I opened and reviewed the code - and it look to be properly in place

So as I thought - git is not always case sensitive - or it would not have renamed both branches.

Once again - thank you!

Jim H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See edits one and two to the original question.

In short - I had two branches with the same name - only difference was in casing.

One was ClientMgr - the first - with only one commit.   From then on - I was working in clientmgr

I did not realize I had two - all along I thought I was working on one.

By what happened here - git is not always case sensitive - so for me - the lesson is always stick to lower case names.

To reslove the issues - I tried to rename ClientMgr to oldclientmgr - but what happened is - it renamed both to oldclient manager.

Luckly - it does not seem anything is lost or otherwise corrupted.

With the dual name problem gone - I renamed oldclientmgr back to clientmgr

Hope this helps anyone else that may have this issue

JimH

Answer (score 2):

If you have continued to work on two separate branches (or did some work on one branch, then on another), you need to merge these changes. This can be done in two ways:

1. You can use `git merge` (when on branch `clientmgr` invoke `git merge ClientMgr`)
2. You can use [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Second solution is a bit harder, especially when you are new to git. Both solutions might need you to resolve conflicts, as changes in both branches may not be compatible. If `ClientMgr` branch was originated directly from `clientmgr` your merge should be `fast-forward`, which means there are no possible conflicts, as all changes in branch `ClientMgr` are made on top of `clientmgr` branch.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  To give a little more background - I thought all this time they were the same single branch.   ClientMgr was the original - with 1 commit.   clientmgr is where I have been working - several commits ahead of ClientMgr.    What I want to do is resolve the situation.    I want to start by renaming ClientMgr to something clearly more unique - but am worried it could cause problems.   In this situation - what is the safest approach to proceed on?   THank you - Jim H

Answer (score 0):

Same just happened to me -- I have no idea why!  I rarely type anything a second time and there were 5 capitals in my branch name.  Would be appreciated if someone knows the cause.

Here is how I fixed it:

```
git checkout BIGBranch
git rebase bigbranch
git push
### verify changes in place then delete duplicate:
git branch -d bigbranch  
git push origin --delete bigbranch
```